# Illegal memory access when using a reference to cudaMalloc'd pointer

Tags: c++, cuda

I want to create a `P` object inside a class and have a `P&`  inside a second class.

This is `P`:

```
struct P
{
    int* p_;

    P() { CC(cudaMalloc(&p_, sizeof(int))); }

    __device__ void print() { printf("p: %d\n", p_[0]); }
};
```

These are my classes:

```
struct A
{
    P a_;
};

struct B
{
    B(A& a) : b_(a.a_) {}
    P& b_;
};
```

This is how I use `P` on the device:

```
__global__ void Ka(A a)
{
    a.a_.p_[0] = 399;
    a.a_.print();
}

__global__ void Kb(B b)
{
    b.b_.print();
}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
A a;
Ka << <1, 1 >> > (a);
CC(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
CC(cudaGetLastError());

B b(a);
Kb << <1, 1 >> > (b);
CC(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
CC(cudaGetLastError());
```

I'm confused because while [on the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8dOL.png) it appears that they are the same object in memory, I get an illegal memory access in the second (`Kb`) kernel call.

How can I achieve something similar without having to copy `P` from `A` to `B`? (in the real scenario `P` can be expensive to copy everytime)

Comment: `a` and therefore the `a_` live in host memory. When you call `Ka` with `a`a as argument, a copy of `a` is created in device memory for the time the kernel is running. The version of `a` that `b` is referencing still lives in host memory. I.e. the reference to the pointer is like a pointer to a pointer and while the object at the end lives in device memory, you can not dereference the pointer to the pointer because it points to host memory. Maybe use unified memory?

Comment: You could have a non-owning `P_view` class that has the `print` method (or whatever it represents in real code). This would also be better according to SOLID (single responsibility principle). So `B` and maybe `A` as well just `P_view` members instead of `P` or `P&`.

Comment: See [gsl-lite](https://github.com/gsl-lite/gsl-lite) for a lightweight implementation of `span` that can be used in device code (i.e. member functions are `__host__ __device__`). Another interesting project might be the RAPIDS Memory Manager ([RMM](https://github.com/rapidsai/rmm)) with its memory resources.

Answer (score 3):

Object `b` is copied to the device when `Kb<<<1, 1>>>(b)` is called, but the reference to `b_` it contains is a host pointer, therefore you cannot dereference it from the device.

In order to address the issue, you can replace the reference to `P` with new instance of `P`.

```cpp
struct B
{
    B(A&& a) : b_(std::move(a.a_)) {}
    P b_;
};

...

B b(std::move(a));
```

In this example, the default move constructor in P will copy `a_.p_` to `b_.p_`. More information on move constructors [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).

For future reference, NVIDIA provides users with a tool called [compute-sanitizer](https://docs.nvidia.com/compute-sanitizer/ComputeSanitizer/index.html) (shipped as part of the CUDA toolkit) that allows you to locate and address these memory issues easily:

```
$ compute-sanitizer --show-backtrace=device ./test
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
p: 399
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 8 bytes
=========     at 0x50 in test.cu:13:P::print()
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x7fff5800cdc0 is out of bounds
=========     and is 257,654,049,729 bytes after the nearest allocation at 0x7fc35aa00000 of size 512 bytes
=========     Device Frame:test.cu:35:Kb(B) [0x10]
=========
========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 719) due to "unspecified launch failure" on CUDA API call to cudaDeviceSynchronize.
=========
test: test.cu:46: int main(): Assertion `(cudaDeviceSynchronize()) == cudaSuccess' failed.
========= Error: process didn't terminate successfully
========= Target application returned an error
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors
```

compute-sanitizer offers several features as:

- Out-of-bounds memory accesses detection (with option `--tool=memcheck`, default if not specified)
- Uninitialized memory accesses detection (with option `--tool=initcheck`)
- Data race detection on shared memory (with option `--tool=racecheck`)
- Invalid synchronization primitives usage (with option `--tool=synccheck`)

If you want to learn more about compute-sanitizer, you can find the documentation for the tool [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/compute-sanitizer/ComputeSanitizer/index.html).

Comment: While this works in principle, OPs code has a memory leak by not implementing a destructor with a call to `cudaFree`. If one implements this destructor, the object doesn't get a default copy constructor anymore (rule of zero/three/five) and one wouldn't want to use it, because then multiple versions of `P` would try to free the same memory. That's why I propose distinguishing by a owning class `P` implementing memory management and a second lightweight class `P_view` which doesn't need a destructor.

Comment: In some situations leaking memory might not be a problem as it will be freed when the CUDA context is destroyed. For code reusability and good style I would still favor doing proper memory handling in the RAII way.

Comment: @paleonix thank you for your comment, I agree that is a valid solution. I will edit the answer to reflect this.